# iAd in UITabBarController with Storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I am trying to add iAd into my tab based app which is setup using Storyboards.  I am following the TabbedBanner example in the iAdSuite sample code from apple.  I have imported the BannerViewController and have set the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UITabBarController* tabBarController = (id)self.window.rootViewController;
CGRect tabBarViewFrame = tabBarController.view.frame;
tabBarViewFrame.origin.y -= application.statusBarFrame.size.height;
tabBarViewFrame.size.height += application.statusBarFrame.size.height;
tabBarController.view.frame = tabBarViewFrame;

self.window.rootViewController = [[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tabBarController];
}
```

I have added the following to my SummaryViewController

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:) name:BannerViewActionWillBegin object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:) name:BannerViewActionDidFinish object:nil];
}
```

The ad is currently appearing below the tab bar? Also, the content of my view has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use `nil` for `bundle` in the last snippet of code. Use `[NSBundle mainBundle]`.